Existence of a direction where a given entire function decays quickly
I wanted to know if for an entire function $f$ that is not a polynomial, there always exists a direction in which the function decays faster than a polynomial. That is, if there exists an angle $\theta$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb N$,
$$
\lim_{z\to\infty} z^n f(ze^{i\theta}) = 0.
$$
For example, for $f(x) = e^{x^k}$, for some positive integer $k$, $\theta = \pi/k$.
If this is not  the case, what stronger assumption could make this true? Maybe $f$ should be transcendental? Of exponential type? Or the path from $0$ to $\infty$ should not always be a straight line?
Note that I don't really have any knowledge in complex analysis.

Thanks for your comment @Conrad ! As I said, I know little about complex analysis. Even though I stumbled on Phragmen Lindelof during my research, I didn't quite caught what you said. Could you please detail your comment as an answer and provide one of those counter-example?

I believe the function $f(x)=\sin(x)$ is a counterexample. This would seem to rule out transcendental as being a sufficient condition, and also any alternate path from $0$ to $\infty$.

sorry I misread the question (I thought it was about the increase on lines and if it must be bigger than any polynomial and for that problem my previous comment about needing finite order applies) - for decay @Steven is absolutely correct and there are easy counterexamples - actually in order less than $1$ an entire function cannot even be bounded on any half line, not to speak of fast decay -

That's unfortunate, I need to find other kind of assumptions then..
